# How would I solve for the Norton Current of this circuit?

Tags: circuit-analysis, current, norton

[image]

How do I solve for the Norton Current of this circuit? The resistance is easy enough, but the box with the resistor and current source is tripping me up. How could I solve for that?

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the short circuit current at the terminals *a* and *b*. You could apply a number of different techniques for this, such as the node-voltage method, the mesh-current method, superposition, and source transformation.

We avoid handing out homework solutions here. Please make a significant effort to solve the problem, and show your work. If you get stuck and have a specific question we will try to help.

Comment: I understand, and appreciate, that this site avoids handing out homework answers. If I wanted an immediate solution, I would have ran a SPICE simulation and been done with it. The main thing that was confusing me the box with the current source in it. I know what Norton Current is, I was just having trouble finding a way to tackle this specific circuit using Nodal or Mesh Analysis. If you have an explanation on which of those methods would be more effective and why it would be appreciated.

Comment: If you knew what Norton Current is you should have said so in the question. If you are having trouble with nodal or mesh methods, **show us your work**. Why **exactly** are you having trouble with the parallel resistor and current source...did you try writing an equation?

Answer (score 0):

For finding short circuit current you can easily use superposition theorem.
Current by voltage source is (192/55) from a to b.
Current by current source can be calculated by using current dividal rule .As we see that current source has 2 resistors among which current is divided.
I(current source)=(4*(35/55)) from b to a.
Hope it helps